# Inserting Multiple Items Into Array At Key Positions

Tags: php, arrays

In my cart class I have a loop:

```
foreach($this->items as $key => $item) {
    $duplicate = clone $item;
    $duplicate->price = 0;
    $duplicate->dynamic = 1;
    // Duplicate new item to cart
    $this->AddItem($duplicate, $key+1);
}
```

Over in the `AddItem` function it does this:
`array_splice($this->items, $position, 0, array($newItem));`

And it works, but the problem is the items are not going in the place I want them too.  This is going to be tricky to explain but hopefully someone can understand.

So lets say for example the $items array is made up of:
`array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`

I end up with:

`array('a', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'b', 'c', 'd')`

But what I want is:
`array('a', 'a2', 'b', 'b2', 'c', 'c2', 'd')`

Because the `$key` value is not changing within the `foreach` loop, it inserts it into the position `$key` of the old `$this->items` array.  But I want the new items to be duplicated *after* their original counterparts.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius `$this->items` is an *array* of class type `CartItems`

Comment: just FYI - from the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) - `" If replacement is not an array, it will be typecast to one (i.e. (array) $replacement). This may result in unexpected behavior when using an object or NULL replacement. "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an additional variable to store the number of dupes to increase the index.

```
$dupes = 0;
foreach ($this->items as $key => $item) {
    $duplicate = clone $item;
    $duplicate->price = 0;
    $duplicate->dynamic = 1;
    // Duplicate new item to cart
    $this->AddItem($duplicate, $key + 1 + $dupes);
    $dupes++;
}
```

See a [live example](https://3v4l.org/bCJN0)

```
class Test 
{
    private $items = ['a','b','c','d'];

    public function dup()
    {
        $dupes = 0;
        foreach ($this->items as $key => $item) {
            $this->addItem($item . '2', $key + 1 + $dupes);
            $dupes++;
        }
    }

    private function addItem($newItem, $position) 
    {
        array_splice($this->items, $position, 0, array($newItem));  
    } 

    public function dump() 
    {
        var_dump($this->items);
    }

}


$test = new Test();
$test->dup();
$test->dump();
```

Output :

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "a2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "b2"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "c2"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "d2"
}
```

Comment: This is really simple and clever.  Thanks!